# onConfigurationChanged() not getting called when manifest has manifest orientation tag

Tags: android

I've looked at many of the other posts for this question and the most common solution is to ensure that you have the following in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.myActivity" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
```

This sub is already in my manifest and I'm **not** forcing my activity' orientation to landscape or portrait yet onConfigurationChanged(...) is not called.

My onConfigureationChanged(...) function is as follows and I am not receiving the logcat output:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

    Logger.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onConfigurationChanged()");

    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

I've also verified that the activity is not going through the standard life cycle by adding loggers in onCreate() and onPause().

Comment: One question, is `Logger` a wrapper class of `Log` that Android uses to log message?

Comment: Sorry should have stripped that down. Just a wrapper of Log so that it can be turned off for release builds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnConfigurationChanged will be called only when the specified config in the AndroidManifest.xml change. For instance, this method will be called after a screen orietation change. If i understood, your app's configs are not changing.

From the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html):

For example, the following manifest code declares an activity that handles both the screen orientation change and keyboard availability change:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Now, when one of these configurations change, MyActivity does not restart. Instead, the MyActivity receives a call to onConfigurationChanged(). This method is passed a Configuration object that specifies the new device configuration.

Comment: that is all true - but my activity is not being restarted and is also not calling onConfigurationChanged. It's rather strange since it's not doing what the documentation says it should

Comment: But this happened even when you rotate your device? The activity is still not going through the standard life cycle?

Comment: this ended up being fixed after rebooting the comp and updating java... not sure why it was going nuts. I'm accepting since you gave me some of your time :)